# How to know earning LN routing fees

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing, core-lightning

I am using c-lightning version:`v0.6-182-g1851ebb`. Is there a way to know how much I have earned routing fees? I found that lnd has `lncli feereport` command that shows earned fees. Does c-lightning have same functionality? If not, is there a way to know earned routing fees?

I created a query for calculating earned routing fees. However, this doesn't work because HTLCs info is removed when a channel forwarded HTLCs closed.

```
sqlite3 $HOME/.lightning/lightningd.sqlite3 "select sum(a.msatoshi - b.msatoshi) from channel_htlcs a inner join channel_htlcs b on a.id = b.origin_htlc"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `lightning-cli listforwards`
>
> List all forwarded payments and their information

Answer (score 0):

I've written a plug-in for c-lightning that emulates `lncli feereport` command of LND. For full functionality, including `day_fee_sum`, `week_fee_sum` and `month_fee_sum` calculations, requires c-lightning v0.7.1 or newer (older versions didn't save timestamps for historical forwards).

https://github.com/kristapsk/lightning-feereport